# Insert locallang values into TypoScript [stdWrap]

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I wonder if it is possible to insert a locallang value into my typoscript wrap / stdWrap object:

I have:

```
singleView {
   related.wrap = <div class="related">Related items: |</div>
}
```

What I need is *something like that*:

```
singleView {
   related.wrap = <div class="related">{LLL:related_items}:|</div>
}
```

**EDIT:**
What I am looking for is an TS equivalent for `$this->pi_getLL` (which works fine).
In our case, we would be replacing values in our extension with
 `$this->cObj->stdWrap($item, $this->conf['singleView.']['related']);`

*locallang.xml* in extensions */pi1* directory:

```
<languageKey index="default" type="array">
    <label index="related_items">Related items: </label>
</languageKey>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
singleView {
   related.dataWrap = <div class="related">{LLL:EXT:myextensionkey/pi1/locallang.xml:related_items}:|</div>
}
```

Of course `related_items` must be a valid locallang key.

**Edit: Do not use `wrap` with `insertData` here, because `insertData` is then run on the whole content, including the user input. If somebody uses `{DB:be_users|0|password}` inside the content you are wrapping, he can just see the password (hash) of the backend user with uid 0.**

Comment: Thanks, but I can't make it happen yet. I used your code and checked the locallang.xml values - but the marker `{LLL:related_items}` is being replaced empty (Well, at least it is being replaced). I don't know where the glitch is, maybe you can give more hints? Is our usage of `$this->cObj->stdWrap` correct?

Comment: Got it now! `{LLL:EXT:myextensionkey/pi1/locallang.xml:related_items}` - Please edit your answer. Points are yours.

Comment: Of course you need a valid LLL: expression ;) I changed the example to include this as well.

Comment: Oh, and I did not delete the `insertData = 1` part. Shame on me :D

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of pgampe here, sadly I don't have enough reputation to do it in a comment.

For easier use, do something like this:

constants:

```
extension.key = myextensionkey
LLL = LLL:EXT:{$extension.key}/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf
```

and in your typoscript:

```
singleView {
   related.dataWrap = <div class="related">{{$LLL}:related_items}:|</div>
}
```